# Kalanchoe wilting

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, watering, succulents, kalanchoe

I bought a kalanchoe around a month ago and have watered it very slightly once every 2 weeks. Recently the leaves have started to turn yellow, soggy and fall on the slightest touch. The soil though is very dry so I'm not sure if I've over or underwatered the plant

Comment: Good question; if could include an overall illustration, & closer illustration of the top & leaves, overall height, current watering amount, current nutrient type & amount & frequency, hours of direct sunlight & hours of diffused light per day, average daytime & average night time temperatures, average humidity, size of container, soil, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Also, you can include illustrations that appear within the text of your questions by clicking on the scenery/mountain silhouette button, and then adding images according the instructions which appear, and you can adjust text of your questions and answers, by clicking on the 'edit' button in the lower left corner of your question screen & answer screen. Thank you! Welcome to the site!